# Geolocation using global map in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, grids-graticules, geolocation

I want to show my study sites (15 from different countries) using a global map in ArcGIS Desktop.

I'd like to show latitudes and longitudes (perhaps with a map grid).

Is there a way to drop pins to show locations, or at least include map grid?

Answer (score 1):

If wizards are enabled, the [Grids and Graticules Wizard](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/map/page-layouts/a-quick-tour-of-the-grids-and-graticules-wizard.htm) in the *Data Frame Properties > Grids Tab* allows you to set up map grids in an layout. In the wizard, choose the graticule option if you want to display lines of latitude and longitude (parallels and meridians). You can choose the type of graticule that you want, change the appearance, symbols, etc. It is also possible to display only markers (point symbols) at the intersections of the grid lines by choosing the "Tick marks and labels" option in the wizard.

[image: Grids and Graticules Wizard]

Appearance options are also available anytime by clicking the "Properties" button in the Data Frame Properties.

[image: Data Frame Properties]